# Init method, memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, initialization

I'm curious about the memory I'm allocating with my factory method.  The idea is, I'll read in a file, and I'll instantiate objects by sending a single unparsed CSV line to my factory method, as such:

```
-(id)initWithCSV:(NSString *)csv
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        NSArray *values = [csv componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        self.city = [values[0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
            [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        self.country = [values[1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
            [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        self.latitude = [values[2] doubleValue];
        self.longitude = [values[3] doubleValue];
    }
    return self;
}
```

My first question is, how is this on memory management?  I'm not completely clear on how ARC works.  My `values` array is destroyed as soon as I `return self;` and exit the method, right?

Second question... is there a more efficient way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: What you're doing is fine.  There are much bigger fish to fry elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your first question:

In this case, ARC doesn't actually make a difference. Since the `commentsSeparatedByString:` method already returns an auto-released object, and you aren't increasing it's retain count (or in ARC terms, creating any strong references), it will be cleaned up automatically when the method returns.

As for efficiency, you could probably save some memory by using NSScanner to scan up to each comma, instead of creating an array with a bunch of strings. But since this is only a few strings that are relatively short, in practice it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

**TL/DR: If you're using ARC, your method is very memory efficient.**

This actually showcases an interesting feature of ARC, having to do with the fact that the output of `componentsSeparatedByString:` is autoreleased.

Say you had this function:

```
while ((line = [self readLine])) {
    [self.lines addObject:[[MyObj alloc] initWithCSV:line];
}
```

Without ARC, this seemingly efficient function could consume a lot of memory because the object in `values` is retained until the autorelease pool is drained. (Same with `line` above actually.)  One traditional way to optimize this is to do as follows:

```
while ((line = [self readLine])) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [self.lines addObject:[[MyObj alloc] initWithCSV:line];
    }
}
```

This way, when you hit the the end of the pool, the autoreleased `values` is deallocated.  You of course, take a performance hit for draining the pool.

An naive ARC implementation would not solve this problem. It would see the +0 output of `componentsSeparatedByString:`, call `[values retain]` and call `[values release]` at the end of scope.

What ARC actually does is call a function `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue(values)` which instead of retaining `values`, removes it from the autorelease pool.  That way when it calls `[values release]` at the end of scope, the array is deallocated.  Likewise, it smartly releases `line` at each iteration of my loop.

This provides excellent memory and CPU efficiency.

Comment: `TL/DR if you're using ARC, this method is very memory efficient`  Are you referring to the method in my original question?

Answer (score 0):

I think that NSArray is released since the scope is limited in the `init` due to autorelease pools. But the values are copied in `self.latitude` for example.